# What is this site (a copy of all the Stackexchange websites)?

Tags: discussion, scraper-sites

http://www.happyforlove.com/questions/c_444314/prove-that-in-an-obtuse-triangle-the-orthocentre-is-the-excenter-of-the-orthic-t

This site is a copy of all the stackexchange websites. I don't know how they're doing it, but all of the questions asked on any stackexchange just appear on that site.

I found this while googling the question I asked on MathStackexchange.

Comment: [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131846).

Comment: Title extended to avoid confusion with "what is MSE" discussions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Now reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189023/228379) (the relevant MSO thread is CW anyway, so I'm not stealing anyone's MSO-rep lunch).

Comment: Now I noticed it was also reported there [on July 12](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules/189023#comment580589_131846), but in a comment, likely overlooked.